# UITableViewCell binding to Data Model (updates driven by FetchedResultsController)

Tags: ios, uitableview, reactive-cocoa

I'm attempting to have my individual `UITableViewCells`: I'd love to have the initial values of the model brought over to their UI representation as well as after the user makes a change have the new UI value brought back to the model. Let's just focus on the latter first: UI changes propagating to the model.

For a little more background understanding, I'm running into an issue when adding a new item. This table is driven by an `NSFetchedResultsController` which sends one `didChangeObject` with a `ChangeInsert` and a second `didChangeObject` for `ChangeUpdate`. The `ChangeInsert` triggers an `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` on the table and the `ChangeUpdate` does a `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`.

Because of these two responses my table view asks for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` twice. This shouldn't be a problem if the same cell is disposed of properly between requests but it doesn't appear to be: I receive an assert that the property in the model is already bound to a `RACSignal`! I've tried any number of ways to be more explicit such as:

`RAC(self.model,value) = [ [RACSignal merge:@[self.valueField.rac_textSignal] ] takeUntil:self.rac_prepareForReuseSignal]`
however the reuse signal does not fire in time as it still asserts (aside, is there a recommended way to directly debug a signal like this firing?)

I've tried adding an additional `takeUntil:[RACObserve(self, model)` to dispose of the signal as soon as the reused cell's model is overwritten (and have it bind to the new model) and understandably this seems to result in the first value disposing. However adding `skip:1` to the observe puts me right back where I am.

Please let me know if there is anywhere else I can add clarity or if you have another way to lay these things out. I'm very new to Reactive Cocoa and still learning best practices :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand your question around the failing `RAC` binding? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, how can I clarify it for you?

Comment: Can you show a code excerpt with more context, to see as much of the picture as possible?

Comment: +1 I don't think ReactiveCocoa has any particular 'best practises' in this area. I would suggest that you post a question onto the RAC GitHub issues. The guys are really helpful over there.

Comment: @yo.ian.g did you ask on Github? Can you share what the final findings were?